# Why we use Unsqueeze() function while image processing?

Tags: python, image-processing, deep-learning, convolution, vgg-net

I was trying to work on a guided project and it was related to image processing. While working on the image processing the instructor used Unsqueeze(0) function for setting up the bed size. I would like to know what happens after changing the bed size. The code is given below for your reference.

I will be very thankfull for a quick response.

```
from torchvision import transforms as T

def preprocess(img_path,max_size = 500):
  image = Image.open(img_path).convert('RGB')

  if max(image.size) > max_size:
    size = max_size
  else:
    size = max(image.size)

  img_transform = T.Compose([
                             T.Resize(size),
                             T.ToTensor(),
                             T.Normalize((0.485, 0.456, 0.406), (0.229, 0.224, 0.225))
  ])

  image = img_transform(image)
  image = image.unsqueeze(0)
  return image
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After this line:

```py
image = Image.open(img_path).convert('RGB')
```

`image` is, possibly, a 3D matrix of some sort. One way that information might be laid out is with dimensions `[Channel, Row, Intensity]`, so you have:

- an R matrix containing many rows each of which contains the intensity values of the Red channel
- a G matrix containing many rows each of which contains the intensity values of the Green channel
- a B matrix containing many rows each of which contains the intensity values of the Blue channel

Now, in machine learning, when we are training a model we are very rarely interested in having only one example. We training on batches of examples. A batch is simply a set of images stacked on top of each other, so we need to go from: `[Channel, Row, Intensity]` to `[Batch, Channel, Row, Intensity]`.

This is what the [`unsqueeze(0)`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.unsqueeze.html) does, it adds a new, zeroth dimension that is used to make the images stackable.

Comment: PyTorch uses the [N, C, H, W] convention for dimensions for images, where N = batch size, C = color channels, H = height, and W = width. You can technically give it anything you want, but usually that's the convention for image processing.

Comment: Thank you Richard for helping me. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4):

The `unsqueeze` is used here likely because you are working with a convolutional neural network.

When you load an image, it will typically have 3 dimensions, **Width, Height,** and Number of **Color Channels**. For black and white images, the number of color channels is 1, for colored images, there are 3 color channels (red, green, and blue, RGB). So, in your case, when you load the image and store it as a tensor, it has shape:

```py
image = img_transform(image) # the resulting image has shape [3, H, W]
```

Note, the reason that the order of dimensions is `[channels, height, width]` and not some other order is because of `PyTorch`. Other libraries/software may do it differently.

However, 3 dimensions is not enough for a 2D Convolutional Neural Network. In deep learning, data is processed in batches. So, in the case of a convolutional neural network, instead of processing just one image at a time it will process `N` images at the same time in parallel. We call this collection of images a batch. So instead of dimensions `[C, H, W]`, you'll have `[N, C, H, W]` (as seen [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Conv2d.html)). For example, a batch of 64 colored 100 by 100 images, you would have the shape:

```py
[64, 3, 100, 100]
```

Now, if you want to only process one image at a time, you still need to put it into batch form for a model to accept it. For example, if you have an image of shape `[3, 100, 100]` you'd need to convert it to `[1, 3, 100, 100]`. This is what `unsqueeze(0)` does:

```py
image = img_transform(image) # [3, H, W]
image = image.unsqueeze(0) # [1, 3, H, W]
```

Comment: Thank you Jay for providing me with a good answer ....... keep helping jay .... thank you once again